# Pandas, create column using previous new column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am using Python and have the following Pandas Dataframe:

| idx | result | grouping |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | False |  |
| 2 | True |  |
| 3 | True |  |
| 4 | False |  |
| 5 | True |  |
| 6 | True |  |
| 7 | True |  |
| 8 | False |  |
| 9 | True |  |
| 10 | True |  |
| 11 | True |  |
| 12 | True |  |

What I would like is to do the following logic...

if the **result** is **False** then I want **grouping** to be the **idx** value.

if the **result** is **True** then I want the **grouping** to be the ***previous grouping*** value

So the end result will be:

| idx | result | grouping |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | False | 1 |
| 2 | True | 1 |
| 3 | True | 1 |
| 4 | False | 4 |
| 5 | True | 4 |
| 6 | True | 4 |
| 7 | True | 4 |
| 8 | False | 8 |
| 9 | True | 8 |
| 10 | True | 8 |
| 11 | True | 8 |
| 12 | True | 8 |

I have tried all sorts to get this working from using the Pandas **shift()** command to using **lambda**, but I am just not getting it.

I know I could iterate through the dataframe and perform the calculation but there has to be a better method.

examples of what I have tried and failed with are:

- `df['grouping'] = df['idx'] if not df['result'] else df['grouping'].shift(1)`
- `df['grouping'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['idx'] if not x['result'] else x['grouping'].shift(1), axis=1)`

Many Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mask` true values then forward fill

```
df['grouping'] = df['idx'].mask(df['result']).ffill(downcast='infer')
```

---

```
    idx  result  grouping
0     1   False         1
1     2    True         1
2     3    True         1
3     4   False         4
4     5    True         4
5     6    True         4
6     7    True         4
7     8   False         8
8     9    True         8
9    10    True         8
10   11    True         8
11   12    True         8
```

Comment: Thanks, this is amazing, I would have never got there without your help.

I never even thought of using a Mask

And it is super fast which I like, less than a second for updating 3.7 million rows.